# PHP ZipArchive | creating unsupported file & not downloading on Cpanel | working on local

Tags: zip, laravel-8, php-ziparchive

hi my goal is to create zip file and download it, working okay on local server but giving problem on Cpanel when i hit download button

```
$fileEntry = FileEntry::with('childEntriesRecursive')->where('shared_id', $shared_id)->notExpired()->firstOrFail();
        abort_if(!static::accessCheck($fileEntry), 404);
         $zip_file = str_replace(' ', '_', $fileEntry->name).'.zip';
            $zip = new ZipArchive();
            $zip->open(public_path($zip_file), ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
            foreach ($fileEntry->childEntriesRecursive as $key => $file) {
                $getFile = storage_path('app/public/'.$file->path);
                if (file_exists($getFile) && is_file($getFile)){
                    echo $file->name;
                    $zip->addFile(storage_path('app/public/'.$file->path), $file->name);
                }
            }
            $zip->close();
          
              return response()->download($zip_file, basename($zip_file))->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
```

output is
[image]